# Error when creating MS Excel docs with VB 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm having some trouble with looping and creating MS Excel docs, code snippet below

```
Private Sub selectedRowsButton_Click( _
ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles selectedRowsButton.Click

    Dim selectedRowCount As Integer = _
        DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)

    If selectedRowCount > 0 Then

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim objexcel As New Excel.Application
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim FACode As Integer
        Dim Sitename As Integer
        Dim Sitecode As Integer
        Dim Address As Integer
        Dim City As Integer
        Dim State As Integer
        Dim ZIP As Integer


        FACode = 1
        Sitename = 5
        Sitecode = 2
        Address = 6
        City = 7
        State = 9
        ZIP = 10
        Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
        xlWorkbook = objexcel.Workbooks.Open("template path")
        For i = 0 To selectedRowCount - 1

            objexcel.Visible = True
            objexcel.Range("B2").Value = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(Sitename).Value.ToString()

            objexcel.Range("B3").Value = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(Sitecode).Value.ToString()

            objexcel.Range("B5").Value = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(FACode).Value.ToString()

            Dim thisfile As Object


            thisfile = objexcel.Range("B5").Value & "." & _
            objexcel.Range("B3").Value & "." & "otherstring" & "." & "otherstring2" & "." & ".xls"

            With objexcel

                xlWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename:="c:\test\" & thisfile)
                '~~> Close the Excel file without saving
                xlWorkbook.Close(False)
            End With          

        Next i

    End If
```

I'm getting the error Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC for the statement

```
  objexcel.Range("B2").Value = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(Sitename).Value.ToString()
```

IF I select only one row of my DataGrid before creating the program works fine, it is when I select multiple rows that this error occurs. Since I'm creating the program specifically for multiple row selections I'm stumped as to where I've gone wrong. Any help or pointers appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know VS2010, but I do notice that you loop through an array with the `For i=` and `Next` but you don't reference it within the loop - Also, as you don't increment the cell reference, all the data will end up on `B2:B5`

Comment: This is confusing, because the formula works when only selecting one row from the DGV, all of the data ends up where it should in cells B2, B3 and B5. I'm only getting errors when selecting multiple rows from the DGV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things

1. You have declared `objexcel` As `Excel.Application` so you shouldn't use `objexcel.Range("B2").Value`. Use `xlWorkbook.Range("B2").Value`. Change it everywhere in your code.
2. You cannot use `SaveAs` like that. See the snapshot below. If you want to save as xls file then you have to use `FileFormat:=56`

See this code example

```
'~~> Save As file
xlWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename:="c:\test\" & thisfile, FileFormat:=56)
```

If you do not specify the file format then you will get an error message when you open the file after opening.

You might want to look at this link on how to automate Excel from VB.Net

**Topic**: VB.NET and Excel

**Link**: http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/

[image]

I am not too sure what you exactly are trying to do with the DGV. Like Sean mentioned you are not incrementing the values. If you can post a snapshot of how your DGV looks and how your Excel file should look after the export then we can help you in a much better way :)

Comment: Thanks - I'll dive back in with these tips and let you know how far I get. Basically the DGV is a list of every building location - I'd like to be able to select multiple rows (locations) and create the worksheets and PDFs needed. The trick is I don't need every column from the row, so I'm using selectedcells

Comment: OK I've got it working properly if I select just one row of the DGV. I'm now stuck with how to choose the correct row of data when looping through the code. Currently it will create and save the first file correctly, and then create a 2nd excel file with the same data as the first. It seems to be populating the data from the first row in the DGV selected everytime, whereas I would like it to loop through each row.